# NO values of field in attribute table is seen in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, editing

I am having a problem in my ArcGIS 10 project.

I had download land use data from my city but while opening attribute table the values for one of the fields (Land use values) are not visible.The file was in Shape format

I Checked the fields in the properties, then also no values are visible in that field.

Whenever I turn on the edit mode, the values are visible.

IF I stop editing mode the values disappear.

While classifying the values from symbology for creating a map, the Map is also not visible. I think the map is created but its not visible.
IfI open the file in Q-GIS then all the fields in attribut table can be seen. I feel comfortable working in Arc gis .

[image]

Comment: By "the Map is also not invisible" do you mean "the Map is also visible" or something else?  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise your question. Was your downloaded data in shapefile, file geodatabase, or some other format?  What were your precise steps from downloading it to seeing the symptoms that you describe?  Please include adding your data to a Blank Map.

Comment: Might be a mismatch between the field definition and the values. Try copying the values into a different field type (text) and look for something odd. You could then create another field of the same type as the original and calculate the values back in to see if you get any errors

Comment: As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.